# Mongoose Document Giving Undefined on second key value pair

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ejs

**Here is my problem i have a itemSchema and i am using this itemSchema as data type of listShecma Second Key value  the listSchema has two propery first name and second items whose data type is [itemSchema] but when i create h new document and save it to lists collection it don't show up on console.log it shows undefinde i have added defailtItem(Sorry its a typo but leave it because i am using same name everywhere and it does not conatin any errors) on console.log defailtItem it show my array with javacript object and it FOLLOWS the itemSchema Here is Some code**

```js
const itemSchema = {
  name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Eat Food"
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Welcom to do list"
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "Press + to add a new item"
});

const defailtItem = [item1, item2, item3];

const listSchema = {
  name : String,
  items : [itemSchema]
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", itemSchema); 

app.get("/:testing", function(req, res){
  const customListName = req.params.testing;

  const listNew = new List({
    name: customListName,
    items: defailtItem
  });
  console.log(listNew.items);
  listNew.save();
});
```

**When i go to mongo command line and find the lists colection it have the name but not items**
[Thats the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Zoh.png)

**Consoel.log of listNew.items gives undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const List = mongoose.model("List", itemSchema); 
to
const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks the problem was solved it was due to so much code and i am a beginner and once again thank you for your answer